# Apply multiple properties to multiple objects

Tags: iphone, ios5, sdk

I am writing an iOS app and I have one question to make the reading easier.

For example, I have many things to hide so I do this like this :
    mytext1.hidden=YES;
    mytext2.hidden=YES;
    mytext3.hidden=YES; 
...

Is there any way to write this :
    (mytext1, mytext2, mytext3).hidden =YES;

?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate an array with a selector like this:

```
[theArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(methodName)];
```

...and there's a variation that takes a single object parameter.  This won't handle scalar types, though, so to set hidden=YES, you can enumerate using a block:

```
[theArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    (UITextField *)obj.hidden = YES;
}];
```

If that's too verbose for your taste, you can add methods to the array class that assume, say, a collection of controls.  These would just conceal the enumeration, but the caller could be as simple as this:

```
[myArrayOfControls hidden:YES];
```

Easy on the eyes, right?  You can achieve this by creating your own custom category of NSArray methods:

```
// in Array+UIControlEnumeration.m

@implementation NSArray (UIControlEnumeration)

- (void)hidden:(BOOL)hidden {

    for (UIControl *control in self) {
        control.hidden = hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, syntax like that doesn't exist in Objective-C. You'd be better off sticking them all in an array that you add as a synthesized property and looping through them like so:

```
for (UITextField *textField in self.myArrayOfTextFields) {
    [textField setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: @danh's answer is much more detailed :)